# QueryDSL maven set up project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, querydsl

I'm followed instructions described in this document http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/2.1.0/reference/html/ch02s02.html

After this, in my Eclipse I have a following error:

```
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: com.mysema.maven:maven-apt-plugin:1.0:process (execution: default, phase: generate-sources)    pom.xml /projectname    line 266    Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem
```

Also, as suggested in QueryDSL documentation I have performed

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

in order to include `target/generated-sources/java` as a source folder and now I have a lot of warnings:

[image]

So my questions are:

1. Is it a correct way to fix `Plugin execution` error by adding a following to my pom.xml:

   ```
   <pluginManagement>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
               <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
               <version>1.0.0</version>
               <configuration>
                   <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                       <pluginExecutions>
                           <pluginExecution>
                               <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                   <groupId>
                                       com.mysema.maven
                                   </groupId>
                                   <artifactId>
                                       maven-apt-plugin
                                   </artifactId>
                                   <versionRange>
                                       [1.0,)
                                   </versionRange>
                                   <goals>
                                       <goal>process</goal>
                                   </goals>
                               </pluginExecutionFilter>
                               <action>
                                   <ignore></ignore>
                               </action>
                           </pluginExecution>
                       </pluginExecutions>
                   </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
   ```
2. Is there a better way in order to include `target/generated-sources/java` as a source folder without performing `mvn eclipse:eclipse` ?

Answer (score 1):

The correct goal to generate sources is: `mvn generate-sources`

This will create the QueryDSL querys before the compile.

Also, the documentation you are looking is for QueryDSL 2.x versions.

Check the newest version! http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.0.7/reference/html_single/

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed these issues by adding the following plugins:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                            <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>target/generated-sources/java</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```